# Cast from list object to class in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to linq and also c#. Here i am facing a problem that, i have to model class

```
public class Product
{
    public int ItemID { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime AuctionEndDate { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class ShoppingCart
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Here i want to create an extension method that will sort all item in my shopping cart.

```
public static ShoppingCart Sort(this ShoppingCart cart)
{

    var sortedCart = from item in cart.Products
                     orderby item.Title ascending
                     select item;
    return sortedCart.ToList();
}
```

So the method will not allow me to return `sortedCart.ToList()`, because this contain List. How can i return shoppingCart? If anyone know please help me. Thanks

Comment: The extension method will need to mutate `cart` in place rather then creating a new list copy of it's list of items.

Comment: maybe return new ShoppingCart() { Products = sortedCart.ToList(); }

Comment: simply create a constructor, that takes a `List<Product>` as Parameter and sets that parameter to Products.
then: `return new ShoppingCart(sortedCart.ToList<Product>());`

Comment: You need to set the value of ShoppingCart.Products not return a random List<object>

Answer (score 6):

Create a new `ShoppingCart` instance and set its `Products` to be the sorted list you just produced:

```
return new ShoppingCart { Products = sortedCart.ToList() };
```

Of course this way the original cart will not be sorted; it's the new (duplicate) cart that will be. If you wanted to sort the original in-place, you should use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) on the original product collection and not LINQ:

```
cart.Products.Sort((x,y) => x.Title.CompareTo(y.Title));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to create a shopping cart from a list of products. You could either use your existing setter or a constructor:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public ShoppingCart(List<Product> products)
    {
        this.Products = products;
    }
...
}
```

Then just `return new ShoppingCart(sortedCart.ToList());`

Answer (score 0):

Why the need of the extension method?

Assuming that the List is already filled just.

```
shoppingCart.Products.OrderBy(x => x.Title);
```

or using the extension method

```
public static void Sort(this ShoppingCart cart)
{

    cart.Products = (from item in cart.Products
                     orderby item.Title ascending
                     select item).ToList();
}
```

or

```
public static void Sort(this ShoppingCart cart)
{  
    shoppingCart.Products.OrderBy(x => x.Title);
}
```